# some questions about fourier inversion formula(Modified)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I struggled lots of time about following problem, but I don't know how to prove following statement.

for $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}) \ \cap\ L^1(\mathbb{R})$, there exist $A > 0$ such that $\left|\hat{f}(w)\right| \leq \frac{A}{W} \forall w \in \mathbb{R} \backslash 0$. ($\hat{f}$ is not necessarily integrable).
Prove that:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{f}(w) e^{iwx} dw $$

How can i prove this statement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh thanks. Since I'm not good at typo, so I will post a picture soon